# Deploy an application onto Azure App service of OS_type Linux with Git as storage. Working for Windows not working for Linux

Tags: git, azure, github, terraform

I used the following terraform code to deploy sample application onto Azure App Service for windows taking .war file from GitHub.

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "GitOpen" {
    location = "East US"
    name = "GitOpenApp"
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "Gitplan" {  
  name                = "Git-plan"  
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.GitOpen.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.GitOpen.name  
  
  sku {  
    tier = "Standard"  
    size = "B1"  
  }  
}   
resource "azurerm_app_service" "Gitapp" {  
  name                = "Git-app"  
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.GitOpen.location 
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.GitOpen.name  
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.Gitplan.id  
  https_only          = true
  
  site_config {
    java_version = "1.8"
    java_container = "TOMCAT"
    java_container_version = "9.0"
    remote_debugging_enabled = true
    
  }
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "sourcecontrol" {
   app_id             = azurerm_app_service.Gitapp.id
   repo_url           = "https://github.com/Username/Repo"
   branch             = "main"
   use_manual_integration = true
   use_mercurial      = false
 }
```

The .war application was fetched from GitHub successfully and I got the output once I clicked on default domain of azure app services.
[image: Opened app in the browser]

Similarly I tried for Azure Linux

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "GitOpenLinux" {
    location = "East US"
    name = "GitOpenAppLinux"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "GitPlanLinux" {
  name                = "Git-Plan-Linux"
  location            =  azurerm_resource_group.GitOpenLinux.location
  resource_group_name =  azurerm_resource_group.GitOpenLinux.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v3"
}  

# Create the web app, pass in the App Service Plan ID
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "GitAppLinux" {
  name                  = "Git-App-Linux"
  location              =  azurerm_resource_group.GitOpenLinux.location
  resource_group_name   =  azurerm_resource_group.GitOpenLinux.name
  service_plan_id       = azurerm_service_plan.GitPlanLinux.id
  https_only            = true
  site_config {
    always_on        = true
  }

  app_settings = {
    "JAVA_OPTS" = "-Dserver.port=80"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "sourcecontrolLinux" {
   app_id             = azurerm_linux_web_app.GitAppLinux.id
   repo_url           = "https://github.com/Username/repo"
   branch             = "main"
   use_manual_integration = true
   use_mercurial      = false
 }
```

I did not get the output. There were no errors in terraform code. It got successful. It was connected to Git in the deployment center as well. But I am not able to see the output.It says application error.
[image: App error]

I tried another way of linux code

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "GitOpenLinux1" {
    location = "East US"
    name = "GitOpenAppLinux1"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "GitplanLinux1" {  
  name                = "Git-plan-Linux1"  
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.GitOpenLinux1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.GitOpenLinux1.name  
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true
  
  sku {  
    tier = "Premiun"  
    size = "P1v3"  
  }  
}  

# Create the web app, pass in the App Service Plan ID
resource "azurerm_app_service" "GitappLinux1" {  
  name                = "Git-app-Linux1"  
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.GitOpenLinux1.location 
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.GitOpenLinux1.name  
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.GitplanLinux1.id  
  https_only          = true
  
  site_config {
    java_version = "1.8"
    java_container = "TOMCAT"
    java_container_version = "9.0"
    remote_debugging_enabled = true
    
  }
 
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "sourcecontrolLinux1" {
   app_id             = azurerm_app_service.GitappLinux1.id
   repo_url           = "https://github.com/Uusername/repo"
   branch             = "main"
   use_manual_integration = true
   use_mercurial      = false
 }
```

It did not show the content.
[image: Not showing content]

Can anyone help me on this. The Git  is connected to the deployment center but not working.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to deploy the app service in Azure for Linux and I was able to provision successively.

Here it seems the message you received, "Your web app is running and waiting for your content," indicates that the deployment was successful, but the content of your application has not been uploaded yet. It mentions that it may take up to 5 minutes for your content to show up

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that you have properly configured and uploaded the content of your .war application to the specified repository `URL`. Make sure the repository URL is correct and accessible. Additionally, ensure that the deployment process has been completed successfully

To overcome these errors my terraform code goes as follows

**main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Xample" {
  location = "East US"
  name     = "demovk"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "GitPlanLinux" {
  name                = "Git-Plan-Linux"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.Xample.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Xample.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true

  sku {
    tier = "Basic"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_web_app" "GitAppLinux" {
  name                = "Git-App-Linuxvksb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.Xample.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Xample.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.GitPlanLinux.id

  site_config {
    java_version            = "1.8"
    java_container          = "TOMCAT"
    java_container_version  = "9.0"
    remote_debugging_enabled = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "sourcecontrolLinux" {
  app_service_id            = azurerm_web_app.GitAppLinux.id
  repo_url                  = "https://github.com/V*******li1/v-b***liv/blob/6cf2**********************a3f567a/sample.war"
  branch                    = "main"
  manual_integration        = true
  repository_type           = "ExternalGit"
  deployment_rollback_enabled = true
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]